# having problems opening DITA files in OxygenXML which contain special characters

Tags: special-characters, dita, oxygenxml

I am having problems opening files which contain special characters like é, è, ë, ê, à, á, ö, etc. The error message I get from OxygnXML is:

```
 File encoding (UTF8) does not support all characters from the current file.
 To ignore these errors or to replace invalid characters follow the link below to change the "Encoding errors handling" option value from REPORT to IGNORE or REPLACE.
```

The strange thing is: when I alter the file (by swapping the 'ó' for an 'o', for instance), I can import the files both in OxygenXML and in FontoXML.Afterwards I can correct them again and save the file. But I don't see a difference between the original file and the altered file.

This is the original file

```
 <p id="id-9f3a1788-a751-4f48-ed9c-9e19447ad3b0">Ze is zó zenuwachtig, dat ze bijna aan de ... moet .</p>
```

And this is the saved corrected file (from FontoXML, in this case - just to show the added instructions):

```
 <p id="id-9f3a1788-a751-4f48-ed9c-9e19447ad3b0">Ze is
                    z<?fontoxml-change-addition-start author-id="erik.verhaar" change-id="6f6bb382-3d43-4c5b-b35f-f857d729cf22" timestamp="1627473671530"?>ó<?fontoxml-change-addition-end change-id="6f6bb382-3d43-4c5b-b35f-f857d729cf22"?><?fontoxml-change-deletion author-id="erik.verhaar" change-id="0296c77c-863b-421f-bf5c-c0901c7a2751" text="ó" timestamp="1627473669483"?>
                    zenuwachtig, dat ze bijna aan de ... moet .</p>
```

What is the difference between the original ó and the corrected one? And how can I change my original files so they can be imported in OxygenXML?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Text files (XML for example) are saved on disk using bytes, they are edited and presented using characters. An encoding takes care of converting bytes to characters (sometimes multiple bytes are converted to characters) when the document is opened and again the encoding does the conversion of characters to bytes when the document is saved.
There are many encodings but with the most popular (like UTF-8) characters belonging to the 0-128 ASCII range like a-z A-Z are usually saved to a single byte. Characters outside of the range, for example e-acute (é) usually get saved as multiple bytes, depending on the encoding used for saving.

When an XML document is opened Oxygen attempts to understand what encoding to use for reading it. If the XML document has a heading like this:

Oxygen uses the encoding specified in the heading. If the XML doc is lacking the heading Oxygen will fallback to UTF-8. Basically Oxygen implements the XML specification when it comes to detecting the encoding of the XML file:
https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-guessing

In your case Oxygen detected the encoding as UTF-8 and started to use UTF-8 to convert bytes to characters. It encountered a sequence of bytes which were not encoded using UTF-8. Oxygen does not continue loading the file because in such cases you may end up with corrupt content when saving it back.

In my opinion the other editor tool you used to create the XML files was not XML aware, it did not actually saved the XML as UTF-8 even if the heading in the XML document specified this.
We do not actually know with what encoding that other editing tool used to save the XML, one thing you could try would be to reopen the XML document in that other editing tool and change its encoding heading declaration from:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

to:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='CP1250'?>
```

because I suspect that other editing tool actually used for saving the XML document the default platform encoding which on Windows should usually be CP1250.
Then save the XML document in the other editing tool and try to re-open it in Oxygen, if it works change its heading encoding declaration back to UTF-8 and save the XML document in Oxygen in order to properly save it using the UTF-8 encoding.

This older set of slides I made about XML encoding might also be useful to you:
https://www.oxygenxml.com/events/2018/large_xml_documents.pdf